# Equivalence of categories and colimits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors, natural-transformations, equivalence-of-categories

Consider functors $F,G:J\to Cat$ which admit colimits and $\eta:F\to G$ a natural transformation such that $\forall i\in J$ $\eta_i:F(i)\to G(i)$ is an equivalence of categories. Is it true that then the induced map from colim$_JF$ to colim$_JG$ is an equivalence of categories ?

Comment: What do you mean by colimit? The strict version or the weak/flexible/bicategorical version?

Comment: Colimit is the data of an object with various morphisms satisfying a commutative triangle and such that for any other object with such maps, there is a unique morphism between both objects satisfying a triangle. Its is written here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory) in terms of cocones.

Comment: So you are asking about strict colimits then? The answer is no in that case.

Comment: I guess I am indeed, I don't have any definition of flexible, weak etc. And if for example we add that $F\dashv G \dashv F$, is it true ? I tried to prove this but there lacks something in my "proof". Maybe it requires another question.

Comment: To remain on this specific question, do you have a counter example maybe if that's not too much to ask for ?

Comment: @ZhenLin Just in case you didn't see the comments

Comment: If you need colimits of diagrams of categories for some reason but you don't know about bicategorical colimits I would strongly recommend you go learn about them and see if they are more appropriate for your purposes. If you are just asking out of curiosity we can leave it at a counterexample.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't "need" it for something particular. Coqualizers and pushouts are bicategorical colimits ? You have a counter example with this kind of colimits ?

Comment: Despite the name bicategorical colimits are not special colimits. (The converse is true in a technical sense but for conceptual purposes it is better to think of them as different things.) Yes, there are examples of coequalisers or pushouts that fail to preserve equivalences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a pushout in $\textbf{Grpd}$ (or $\textbf{Cat}$ – there is no difference with respect to colimits) that is not equivalence-invariant.

Consider the inclusion of the discrete groupoid $\{ 0, 1 \}$ into the "interval" $\mathbf{I} = \{ 0 \cong 1 \}$, which is the groupoid with two objects and a unique morphism between any two objects.
Let $\mathbf{S}$ be the groupoid with two objects $0$ and $1$, with $\textrm{Hom}_\mathbf{S} (x, y) = \mathbb{Z}$ for any objects $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbf{S}$, and composition given by integer addition.
Then we have the following pushout square in $\textbf{Grpd}$:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\{ 0, 1 \} @>>> \mathbf{I} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathbf{I} @>>> \mathbf{S}
\end{CD}$$
(Incidentally, the above is also a bicategorical pushout square.)

On the other hand, $\mathbf{I}$ is equivalent to the "point" $\{ \bullet \}$, and the following is also a pushout square in $\textbf{Grpd}$:
$$\begin{CD}
\{ 0, 1 \} @>>> \{ \bullet \} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\{ \bullet \} @>>> \{ \bullet \}
\end{CD}$$
Yet, $\mathbf{S}$ is not equivalent to $\{ \bullet \}$.
This demonstrates that pushouts are not equivalence-invariant.

(The "reason" is that the second square is *not* a bicategorical pushout square.
The bicategorical pushout of $\{ \bullet \} \leftarrow \{ 0, 1 \} \rightarrow \{ \bullet \}$ "is" $\mathbf{S}$, or if you insist on a model making the diagram strictly commute, the one-object groupoid $\mathbf{B} \mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ as the group of automorphisms of the unique object.
Of course, $\mathbf{B} \mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{S}$.)

Comment: So here the functors would be $F,G:\text{Span}\to Cat$ defined on objects by $I$ and $\{\bullet\}$ on 1 and 2 am I right ? Moreover are there 1 or 2 non zero morphisms in $I$ ? Because I didn't know about this and the first definition says there is a unique morphism from 0 to 1 (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/interval+category). And finally you say there is no difference between Grpd and Cat here but you define Hom$_S(x,y)$ as a group, is there a way to do it without ?

Comment: Same as before just to be sure that you get a notification. I also want to add that to remain in Cat we can say that S is the category with 2 elements and $\mathbb N$ isomorphisms from 0 to 1, in this sense we don't say its a groupoid although it is am I right ? @ZhenLin

Comment: No, everything stays in the same in $\textbf{Cat}$. I mean the groupoid $\mathbf{I}$ here, so there is a morphism $0 \to 1$ and also $1 \to 0$.

Comment: And what about $F$,$G$ in my previous comment ?

Comment: I don't know precisely what you meant. The diagram shape is correct.

Comment: Recall that initially we wanted the data of two functors such that the induced map between colimit is or isn't an equivalence. So with your counter example we want a functor whose pushout is $S$ if I understand correctly.  So I meant $F(0)=\{0,1\}$, $F(1)=F(2)=I$ and on morphisms $F(s:(0\to1))$ the most natural functor between $\{0,1\}$ and $I$. Same for $t:0\to2$. The functor we want is probably already in your answer but I need to write it clearly for myself. @ZhenLin

Comment: Right. I think you can figure it out yourself now.